# How to make back and forward buttons of web browser trace the path of my internal components and navigate accordingly in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, browser-history

Below is the explanation of my code

I have multi stepper application in that I have stepA and stepB

**stepA has 3 substep**

**stepB has 2 substep**

**stepA and stepB has their separate routes** something like below

file - routers.js

```
<Route path={`/step-a`} render={()=><StepA history={this.props.history}/>} />
<Route path={`/step-b`} render={()=><StepB history={this.props.history}/>} />
```

main.js

```
import Routers from './routers';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory({ forceRefresh: true });

ReactDOM.render(<Routers history={history} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**The substep are internally rendering they don't have their own routes**

StepA.js

```
componentDidMount(){
let selfThis = this;
 window.addEventListener('popstate', function(popStateEvent){
      if(popStateEvent.state){
        if(popStateEvent.state.state){
          selfThis.setState({current:popStateEvent.state.state});
        }
      }
    })
}

changeRoute(){
let current = this.state.current;

if(current <= 3){
  this.setState((prevState)=>({current: prevState.current+1}),()=>
  this.props.history.push({state: this.state.current})
 );
 }else{
   this.props.history.push('/step-b');
 }
}

render(){

const {current} = this.state;

 if(current===1){
   return(<div>This is Step A substep 1 <button 
 type="button" onClick={this.changeRoute}>Next</button></div>)
 }
 else if(current === 2){
   return(<div>This is Step A substep 2 </div>)
 }else {
   return(<div>This is Step A substep 3 </div>)
 }

}
```

**What did i expect**

I just want my browser to make its back and forward button trace the path of my internal components i.e. StepA substep 1 > StepA substep 2 and navigate accordingly

If I click on next and I am on StepA substep 1 then I must go on StepA substep 2 not stepB directly.

**Note** - The above code may contain bugs as I have written the fresh code not the original one.

**Whats the issue**
During the change of routes i.e. going from stepA subtep3 to stepB subtep1 it gets problem when I hit the browser back or forward button then at that instance this functionality doesn't work properly, and I think this maybe the issue related to the other history.push('/step-b') but I'm unable to resolve it.